# Python bad interpreter: No such file

Tags: python, ubuntu

Не могу на гитлабе запустить обычный скрипт на питоне - сталкивался может кто?

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
$ src/py_tests/server_tests.py
/usr/bin/bash: src/py_tests/server_tests.py: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Думаю в начале скрипта у вас строка типа `#! my_venv\Scripts\python.exe`.
Путь указанный там вероятно неверен. Попробуйте  указать верный путь или удалить строку и запустить скрипт как `python3 src/py_tests/server_tests.py`

Answer (score 0):

У вас отсутствует /usr/bin/python

Установите python 2-й версии